# Creating a single SmartTV app for multiple platforms of Samsung and LG

Tags: sdk, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I want to create a smart TV app for samsung and LG, which should run on their specific platforms.

The app should be capable of running on the below platforms of LG:-

- LG Smart TV SDK V3.0.
- LG Smart TV SDK V2.4.0
- webOS TV SDK 1.2.0

The app should be capable of running on the below platforms of Samsung:-

- SDK 3.5
- SDK 4.5
- SDK 5.1

If i develop an app for any of these SDK, what are the dependencies in porting it to the other platforms/SDKs.
My undestanding is that core components like the Player and Remote Control Management are platform specific.And you would need to use a configuration file and implements these components independently for each platform.

And between creating the app for LG and sumsung is there any common SDK to develop app once and run on any platform.Could find about "Smart Tv Alliance", but samsung does not support it and is very recent.

Any pointer or suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross platform development on Smart TV it is a little tricky. I would suggest you to have a look at some cross platform SDK already out there.

Here a brief list:

**INIO TV** from [Mautilus Software](http://www.mautilus.com/)

http://www.inio.tv

Source code free and open source at
https://github.com/mautilus/inio-sdk-js

I used in the past, it works well for Samsung and LG.

**Tv App Engine**

http://www.tvappagency.com

I think it is proprietary and I could not find information about their fees.

**Joshfire Smart TV SDK**

http://framework.joshfire.com/

I had not opportunity to test it yet but it seems LG is not supported.

I hope it can helps.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is a free and opensource Smartbox library:

https://github.com/immosmart/smartbox

In my opinion rather good one =)